# $\mathbb{Q}$ is not locally compact using baire category?

Tags: general-topology, baire-category

is there any result related together with Baire Category Theorem, Locally compactness, and Completeness? actually I would like to prove $\mathbb{Q}$ is not locally compact.
I realize that singleton sets $\{r_i\}$ are Nowhere dense in $\mathbb{Q}$ as it has empty interior!
Thank you for discussion and help

Comment: It is a standard fact that every locally compact space satisfies the Baire category theorem (see, e.g., the Wikipedia article "Baire Category Theorem") so that you are done.  There are, of course, simpler and more direct ways of seeing that the rationals are not locally compact.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It follows immediately from one form of the Baire category theorem that $\Bbb Q$ is not locally compact. Specifically, it follows from the form called BCT$2$ [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baire_category_theorem). The sets $U_q=\Bbb Q\setminus\{q\}$ for $q\in\Bbb Q$ are dense and open in $\Bbb Q$, and there are countably many of them, so if $\Bbb Q$ were locally compact, their intersection would be dense. Of course it’s not dense; on the contrary, $\bigcap_{q\in\Bbb Q}U_q=\varnothing$, so $\Bbb Q$ cannot be locally compact.

Of course there are much more direct arguments, but if you have the Baire category theorem on hand, it does provide a very short argument.

Answer (score 3):

See [Analysis Tools with Examples](http://www.math.ucsd.edu/~bdriver/DRIVER/Book/anal2p.pdf) p 150, for another version of the Baire Category theorem when $X$ is a locally
compact Hausdorff space.